# Member of base class template is out of scope in derived class template with same template argument

Tags: c++, templates

The following code gives me a compilation error *'value' was not declared in this scope*.

```
template<class T>
struct Base {
    int value;
};

template <class T>
struct Derived : public Base<T> {
    int getValue() { return value; }
};
```

I find it extremely odd that

- if `Derived` inherits from `Base<std::string>`, the code compiles,
- if I `return Base<T>::value`, the code compiles.

Why doesn't the code compile as it is? In what way is 'value' not declared in the scope of `Derived<T>::getValue()`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because `value` is an *unqualified name*, and during the first phase of name lookup, the compiler will have no clue that this is a data member inherited from a base class (it hasn't instantiated `Base<T>` yet). Thus, it will search the global namespace, and find no variable called `value`; consequently, it will emit an error.

Here is a typical approach to solve this problem:

```
template <class T>
struct Derived : public Base<T> {
    int getValue() { return this->value; }
    //                      ^^^^^^
};
```

Explictly dereferencing `this` tells the compiler that the name that follows is the name of a (possibly inherited) data member, and the lookup should be delayed to the point where the member function is actually instantiated. Of course, your solution of doing:

```
return Base<T>::value;
```

Is equally good, because it also tells the compiler that `value` is inherited from the base class `Base<T>`.

For what concerns deriving from `Base<std::string>`, the compiler can immediately go and look up whether `Base<std::string>` contains a data member named `value` (because it does not depend on any template parameter) and if that is the case, it will be able to determine that the expression is well-formed.

However, if your base class is `Base<T>`, where `T` is unknown during the first phase of name lookup, the compiler can't tell what `value` is (specializations of `Base` for different `T`s may even not have `value` at all).

Paragraph 14.6/3 of the C++11 Standard:

> In the definition of a class or class template, if a base class depends on a template-parameter, the base class
>   scope is not examined during unqualified name lookup either at the point of definition of the class template
>   or member or during an instantiation of the class template or member. [...] [*Example*:
>
> ```
> struct A {
>     struct B { / ... / };
>     int a;
>     int Y;
> };
>
> int a;
>
>   template<class T> struct Y : T {
>     struct B { / ... / };
>     B b; // The B defined in Y
>     void f(int i) { a = i; } // ::a
>     Y* p; // Y<T>
>   };
>
> Y<A> ya;
> ```
>
> The members `A::B`, `A::a`, and `A::Y` of the template argument `A` do not affect the binding of names in
>   `Y<A>`. —*end example* ]

Comment: Excellent, as always might I add :).

Comment: What if I want to use a `typedef name` of  base class in the sub class?