# Out of scope error using friend class and templates in C++

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to read the `int data` variable in parent class `Foo` in child class `Bar`.

The variable `data` is initialized under a `private:` and uses `friend class Bar<T>`.

I am receiving the following compiler error:

```
$ g++ scopetest.cpp
scopetest.cpp: In constructor ‘Bar<T>::Bar()’:
scopetest.cpp:33:12: error: ‘data’ was not declared in this scope
    cout << data;
            ^
```

I thought `friend class Bar<T>` would make everything under `private:` visible to `Bar<T>`. But this doesn't seem to be the case.

Here is my code:

```
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Bar; 

template <typename T> 
class Foo{
    private:
        friend class Bar<T>;
        int data;

    public:
        Foo() {
            data = 0;
        }

        ~Foo() {

        } 

};

template <class T>
class Bar : public Foo<T> { 
    public: 
        Bar<T>() : Foo<T>() {  
            cout << data;   
        }

        ~Bar() { }

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){   

}
```

Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: @dvnrrs I've done this, and it still throws an out of scope error. Removed the friend declaration and changed it to protected. Hrm.

Comment: @dvnrrs After reading the other answer, it works now that I put `this->data`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that if it's `protected`. (It won't hurt, but it may be a sign something wasn't done quite right.) If you post your attempt I'll see if I can spot the problem.

Comment: I see. I was afraid of that. Posting now.

Comment: It's up there now. It throws the exact same out of scope error.

Comment: Also unsure why this isn't working, but it might be worth noting that since you don't need the friending anymore you no longer have to forward declare class Bar above Foo. I also don't think you need to use the template in Bar's default ctor, might be able to just say `Bar() : Foo<T>()`

Comment: I looked into this further this morning and discovered that it's a peculiar (to me) [behavior of templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813863/member-of-base-class-template-is-out-of-scope-in-derived-class-template-with-sam). If you try this with non-template classes, it works fine (you can access the `protected` member without `this->`). But because of the way templates work, the compiler requires you to use `this->` (see the link for a discussion). I did not know this. So, awesomeyi's answer below is correct: use `protected` and access it with `this->`.

Comment: Using this-> to access the parent class field seems a bit weird, but it works. I wonder why the language was designed like this for templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `data` with `this->data`, live demo: http://ideone.com/UNR0IM. Note that this is the far from optimal solution. The `protected` access specifier was made just for this purpose.

```
class Foo
{
    protected:
        int data;
 ....
}
```

Comment: This solution works, but I am definitely interested in doing it the suggested proper way. However, using protected and removing the friend statement like @dvnrrs suggested still yields an out of scope error?

Comment: @Bob you can do `Bar<T>::data` or `this->data` with the proper method